# update or insert item based on existence in table dynamodb python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

### The Problem

I'm trying to look into table item by item, so that if an item already exists then I should be able to update it, if not then I should be able to insert it.

However, I learnt that update works like upsert(update/insert) as well. My case doesn't suit that as well.

### My Case

1. Check if `item` exists in table and store the `flag` (boolean)
2. Check if `flag` is `0`, (item not available) then, insert the item and add current timestamp into column `Inserted_dttm`
3. Check if `flag` is `1`, (item available) then, update the item and add current timestamp into column `Updated_dttm` (and not Inserted_dttm)

### The Trial

I've been looking `query()` is a good option over `get_item()`, however your solutions are welcomed with any of it.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    x = TrainDataProcess()
    file_name = 'Training_data/' + event['file_name']
    s3.Object(bucket_name, file_name).download_file('/tmp/temp.xlsx')
    table_name = 'training_data'

    x.load_excel(name='/tmp/temp.xlsx')
    x.load_headers(skiprows=0)
    x.data_picking()

    table = dynamoDB_client.Table(table_name)
    load = x.return_records_json()

    try:
        with table.batch_writer() as batch:
            for record in load:
                flag = table.query(TableName=table_name, )
                if flag == 0:
                    record['inserted_dttm'] = get_dttm()
                    batch.put_item(Item=record)
                elif flag == 1:
                    record['updated_dttm'] = get_dttm()
                    batch.update_item(Item=record)
            return True
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DynamoDB has the concept of conditional expressions (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) which you can use to identify if you are upserting or inserting.

Unfortunately, however, it does not have the ability to dynamically change the insert/update depending on the result of the condition. i.e. you can enforce that the `Updated_dttm` is only set on an update, and `Inserted_dttm` is only set on an insert, but you cannot do both in a single operation.

You can, however, do this in two steps (for now I'll assume updates are more common than inserts, but you can reverse the logic if that is not true):

1. Attempt to update (set `Updated_dttm`) with the condition `attribute_exists(PARTITION_KEY_NAME)`
2. If that fails with `ConditionalCheckFailedException` then assume inserting (set `Inserted_dttm`)

n.b. if you have a partition and sort key you'll need to use the condition `attribute_exists(PARTITION_KEY_NAME) and attribute_exists(SORT_KEY_NAME)`

Comment: Tried it, landed few errors again. However found another way out to do the same.

Comment: Interesting- `ConditionalCheckFailedException` will be thrown as an error that you'll have to catch, if that's what you mean? You should share your solution too, as it might help someone else!

Comment: Yes Thomas, I'll cut down the clutter of code; once I'm available and post the solution.